# sklearn KNN regression does not give 0 training error for k=1

Tags: scikit-learn, knn

I am trying out sklearn's KNN regressor.
I expect it to have 0 training error for k=1.
I am getting a mean square training error of 0.071.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out.
When two training samples have same input and different output, the regressor doesn't consider both for k=1. It considers only one of them.